# How can I use pagination in combonation with begins_with?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How can I take advantage of using "LastEvaluatedKey" for pagination when my query uses `begins_with` on a single-table design with a `#` delimiting my values? My page size is Limit=100 and there are several thousand items, so it would pass the 1MB limit.

PK = "Prefix#UID" ("GBUID # d2pZ3XMA")

SK = "Channel_ID#Date#Message_ID" (

My `LastEvaluatedKey` looks like this:

`{'pfx': 'GBUID', 'pk': 'd2pZ3XMA', 'sk': 'dfc8ad08-bfbe-45ef-8cf0-6a38a7d881bb#2021-10-30T01:14:52.997Z#714bdc31-5443-4489-a6f0-39bc9f838e3e'}`

I'm having trouble wrapping my imagination on how I'm able to continue using `begins_with` to retrieve all Items that have the UID that begins with a specified channel id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it can be done with some finessing. Once you receive your `LastEvaluatedKey` value then you will switch gears to use an `lt` or `gt`query.

`ddb.Table("table_name").query(KeyConditionExpression=Key("pk").eq(LEK["pk"]) & Key("sk").lt(LEK["sk"])`

(depending on which way your `ScanIndexForward` is going i.e True/False) and then query accordingly using some form of pagination loop.

You will need to filter out the keys that you don't want. Luckily, since Dynamodb sorts everything via `UTF-8` it will be towards the tail-end of your response.

In my case, my loop would stop when channel_id no longer equals `begins_with` value (channel_id).